# Yii model default values. DRY

Tags: model, yii, dry

I am codding multiuser application.And in each model I have a field user_id, every user login and i can get him id: `Yii::app()->user->id`.

I don't want to repeat it in every action find/update/inset condition so How can I set this in model user_id?

Comment: Isnt this stuff solvable with Yii's RBAC system?

Comment: I dont think, in RBAC system checking access, but not setting default datat for models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CActiveRecordBehavior. That way you can hook the beforeFind/afterFind and beforeSave/afterSave events for all of your models. It's really quite nice

Comment: Nice. I create behavior, but in each model i shoud use some: <!-- language: html --> public function behaviors()
    {
        return array(
            // Classname => path to Class
            'ModelBehavior'=>  'application.behaviors.AccountIDBehavior',
        );
    }

Comment: How can i use it only one time, in config for example?

Comment: Don't think you can add it in the config. You could add it to your parent ActiveRecord class, but would then need to be careful to merge behaviors in you model classes with your parent behaviors array

Answer (score 0):

You have to create parent class and inherit it

```
abstract class UserAccess extends CActiveRecord {

    public function getUserAccessCondition($condition, array $params)
    {
        if ($condition instanceof CDbCriteria) {
            $condition->compare('user_id', Yii::app()->user->id);
        } else {
            if(!is_array($condition)) {
                $condition['condition'] = $condition;
                $condition['params'] = $params;
            }
            if (trim($condition['condition']) == '') $condition['condition'] = 'user_id=:user_id';
            else $condition['condition'] .= ' and user_id=:user_id';
            $params[':user_id'] = Yii::app()->user->id;
        }
        return $condition;
    }

    public function find($condition='',$params=array())
    {
        $condition = $this->getUserAccessCondition($condition, $params);
        parent::find($condition, $params);
    }
    // and so on in findAll,  findAttributes...
    // for findByPk you need make some things maybe after find 
    // chek user_id and if is not equal throw access denied exception 
    public function afterFind()
    {
        if ($this->user_id != Yii::app()->user->id) {
            throw new CHttpException(403, 'Access Denied');
        }
    }
}


class UserItem extends UserAccess
{
   //.. rules tableName etc

}
// simple call
$userItem = UserItem::model()->find('name=:name', array(':name' => 'Some search name'));
```

Comment: I should override every method, that i will use... May be, create component (as Controller, which inherit  from CController) will be better, and inside component override this methods?

Comment: @Actimele, yes U can do it in a parent controller class, if you will use it only in controllers.